# Configuring document expiration library and auto deletion on SharePoint Online

Tags: workflow, document, expiration

I am trying to configure auto deletion on my site by setting up a document expiration policy for some documents in my site document library and specifying a retention stage to delete the documents at `(created + 1 day)` for testing purpose.

However, files are still there when the policy expires, I configured a policy to be on the library & folders level and then changed to the site content types when the first didn't work, but documents do not get deleted in both cases. Also declaring a document as record option doesn't seem to be available.

Any idea on how to configure a document library to automatically delete expired documets or files, and how to declare a documet record? would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should operate in the same manner as on-prem, with the cavet we don't have control over the timer jobs that handle this. Looking at my 2010 farm, the 2 timer jobs which I assume are in the 2013 version, are called Information management policy and expiration policy. The default for these is to run weekly. One process markes the files expired then the oher comes through and cleans them up.

Since we don't have control over these in O365, it could be these are running weekly instead of daily or even more frequently and thus haven't processed the expired files yet.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I will try increasing the duration of the policy ans see if that gets processed, will update with the results.